# I want to search on search bar with two field like"Name"&"Discription" using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This below code is my search code ,I have search using only one field I want to search with tow field How can I do that ,first field is "Name" & second is "Discription"

```
 string searchText = EnteredText == null ? "" : EnteredText.ToLowerInvariant();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    CustomProgressDialog.Instance.ShowLoading(AppResources.TitleLoading);
                    var tempList = AllStories.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText));
                    MyStories = new ObservableCollection<Story>(tempList);
                    if (MyStories?.Count<1)
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IToastMessage>().LongAlert(AppResources.MsgStoryotFound);
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    MyStories = new ObservableCollection<Story>(AllStories);
                }
```

Comment: What about `.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText) || x.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchText))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a sequence of `Stories`, where every `Story` has two string properties: `Name` and `Description`. You also have some `searchText`.

> **Requirement** Give me all Stories from the collection of `Stories` that have a Name or a Description that contains at least `searchText`.

Usually if you want to see if a text contains another text, you use one of the overloads of [Enumerable Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0):

```
IEnumerable<Story> allStories = ...
string searchText = ...
var storiesWithSearchText = allStories.Where(story =>
    story.Name.Contains(searchTest) || story.Description.Contains(searchText));
```

In words: from the sequence of allStories, keep only those stories that have a Name that contains searchText and/or have a Description that contains searchText.

You need to use the overload with a stringComparer If you don't want exact text comparison, but some smart text comparison. For instance if you want to ignore case, or maybe such that diacritics are treated as if it is without diacritics: searchString `senor` will also match `señor`, and `francais` will also match `Français`.

Note: ToLower will only work on texts that have no diacritics. Are you sure that your operator will never type any?

```
IComparer<string> comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

var storiesWithSearchText = allStories.Where(story =>
    story.Name.Contains(searchTest, comparer) ||
    story.Description.Contains(searchText, comparer));
```

There is no string comparer that ignores diacritics. Luckily it is easy to create one.

```
class StringCompareIgnoreDiacritics : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    private CultureInfo CultureInfo => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    IEqualityComparer<string> Comparer =>
        StringComparer.Create(this.CultureInfo, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);

    public bool Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return this.Comparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string x)
    {
        return this.Comparer.GetHashCode(x);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IComparer<string> comparer = new StringCompareIgnoreDiacritics();
var storiesWithSearchText = allStories.Where(story => ... etc, see above
```

I deliberately put the Culture and the Comparer properties as separate properties, to minimize changes. So if you want case sensitivity, or maybe only compare in Spanish, you'll only have to change one line.